# Advice on complex CakePHP page

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I was just looking to get advice from people who have experience with CakePHP.

Basically I've done most of my site using CakePHP, and most of it was very standard stuff. Pages to add, edit and view various tables in the database essentially (things like students, classes, lessons etc. - it's an app for a school). So that stuff was straightforward. No more than 1 or two associations.

But now I have to do a bit that's a little more complicated and I'm afraid if I do it the normal CakePHP way with loads of associations then the amount of queries per page will get massive.

Basically it's a section of the site where you can build the timetable for different class groups. An entry in the timetable consists of a course id, a user id (which refers to the teacher), a classgroup id (the class that's taking it), a time/date and then also the option to add it for multiple weeks. So for example:

1st Year students are doing Biology with Mr. Smith at 9AM on Monday, for next 9 weeks starting 22/05/2013.

There are no repeating events in the database, the above should just create 9 entries.

I have no idea how I'd approach this in the CakePHP way. Would I be better off doing manual queries/inserts etc.? I'm tempted to but I know that sort of stuff is considered bad practice when using a framework like this. Or can CakePHP manage this sort of stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Without out and out writing your code for you, I think the answer is:  there is no problem doing it the CakePHP way and it would probably be a bad idea to do it any other way.

**More Explanation:**

If you need the data, then you need the data - bottom line.  If you're caching like you should be, this won't be a big issue even if you have a LOT of queries.

The other option would be to re-think your database if you really have "too many" querires - but it sounds like you're using conventions, so I wouldn't be concerned.

Example - I just checked a page on a quite-complex site we built (with debug on) and it had 119 queries on the homepage (seemingly a lot) that took only 22ms.

Lastly - CakePHP is just generating MySQL - so if you're able to build the queries you want with MySQL, you can probably build them (and likely easier) WITH CakePHP.  I have made a bunch of CakePHP sites with a wide variety of subjects, structures...etc, and have almost literally never needed to manually build a query.

Comment: Ok so basically I shouldn't be worried if CakePHP is generating a few queries per page. This was my main concern and I thought it meant I was doing something wrong. I'll go the standard route so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep - not a problem.  Also remember - if you're in development mode (debug 2), there will often be many queries you don't expect, but ones that won't appear if you're in production mode (debug 0).  This is because it tries to update your database schema...etc etc. during development mode.

Comment: Good answer, also, if queries are getting too complicated, sometimes it may be worth using database views as an 'abstraction' layer. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html). Database views will *not* directly improve performance, but are in many situations more convenient to use and may give you more control over the queries that are executing, off-loading some things to the database in stead of (Cake)PHP